# Android ExoPlayer demo: continue playback with screen locked

Tags: android, android-notifications, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, foreground-service

I want to modify the ExoPlayer demo to allow audio playback to continue when the screen gets locked (this should work regardless of whether the media being played is audio or video). Based on some hints (e.g. [1](https://exoplayer.dev/troubleshooting.html#how-do-i-keep-audio-playing-when-my-app-is-backgrounded), [2](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/playback-notifications-with-exoplayer-a2f1a18cf93b)) this is what I came up with so far:

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/compare/release-v2...sedubois:background-playback

This is directly based on the ExoPlayer demo code, currently in version 2.12.1. It adds a "foreground" permission, registers a service, and creates a notification in that service (according to the documentation this notification is required for background playback). The service is started when initializing the player.

I can start the player and the demo looks as illustrated below with an audio stream. At this point the notification gets created properly, it shows the player details (title, description, progress bar) and control buttons (see picture below), which work (I can play/pause, restart from the beginning and skip backwards/forwards).

However the playback still stops when I minimize the application or when I lock the screen by pressing the power button. What is the proper way to make this work?

[image: ExoPlayer]
[image: Notification]

Comment: Probably, it stops the playback in your activity's onStop/onPause methods.

Comment: Thank you @sdex, should I just check for `!player.isPlaying()` in the if statements of those methods? What about when resuming? If I do this it allows the playback to continue when screen is locked but when unlocking the screen the audio jumps back to the position it was when screen had gotten locked.

Comment: Also, if I just add a check `!player.isPlaying()` in onPause/onStop, then the player does not stop when exiting the player by hitting the back button, and so it crashes when entering it again.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure we are on same page. I'm testing on `dev-v2` branch of exoplayer repo [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/dev-v2)

`onStop()` method in `PlayerActivity.java` is releasing player, So when app goes in background then `onStop()` is being called and it is releasing player with method `releasePlayer`.
If you'll comment out that method i.e. dont release player in `onStop()`, then player will play in background.

Comment: Yes @Harneev, removing releasePlayer allows player to continue in background. But that also lets the player continue when staying in the app but navigating away using the back button (problem #1). Then when re-entering the player by selecting another track, the player crashes (problem #2). How to make sure the player only continues when minimized or when screen is locked, but not when leaving the player screen while staying in the app?

Comment: That'll be activity lifecycle handling that you'll need to handle on your own. Methods like `onUserLeaveHint` can notify when user has pressed home or moved to another application or `onBackPressed` can notify when user moves back to previous activity or screen. This video might help you with your background playback implementation as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svdq1BWl4r8&t=1160s